# How to pass csv file as input through command line?

Tags: php, sql, database, csv, command

I was given a task to do and I was not sure how to pass the csv file as in command file, so I hard code it in my code. But, I would still like to learn how to do it? Any help is appreciated.

Create a PHP script, that is executed from the command line, which accepts a CSV file as input
(see command line directives below) and processes the CSV file. The parsed file data is to be
inserted into a MySQL database.

```
The PHP script should include these command line options (directives):
• --file [csv file name] – this is the name of the CSV to be parsed
• --create_table – this will cause the MySQL users table to be built (and no further
• action will be taken)
• --dry_run – this will be used with the --file directive in case we want to run the
script but not insert into the DB. All other functions will be executed, but the
database won't be altered
• -u – MySQL username
• -p – MySQL password
• -h – MySQL host
• --help – which will output the above list of directives with details.
```

What I did is hard code the csv file in my php file. How can I accept the csv file as input through command line?

My code:

```
<?php 
require 'database.php';

$lines = file('users.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);

$col_names = array_shift($csv);


$users = [];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name, surname, email) VALUES (?,?,?)'); 
foreach($csv as $row) {
    $users[] = [
        $col_names[0] => ucfirst(strtolower($row[0])),
        $col_names[1] => ucfirst(strtolower($row[1])),
        $col_names[2] => strtolower(strtolower($row[2])),
    ];
}

foreach($users as $user) {
    $stmt->execute($user);
}

?>
```

Comment: [How to pass parameters to your php script](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/12/07/how-to-pass-parameters-to-your-php-script-via-the-command-line/)

Comment: @RamyHerrira It does not show any csv file example unfortunately

Comment: Sorry but you won't always find a specific answer to your problem ! Here you have to pass to your script the name of your csv file. In this case the name is 'users.csv' so you would execute your script like this `php script.php --file=users.csv`.
The article I just showed you explains how to do that with the function `getopt`

Comment: I see. But if I pass it like that how do I change in my code so I can use that file value in my php script? @RamyHerrira

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to define the options that you would like to accept, in this case we just defined the option "file".

```
$options = ['file:'];
```

Then when you execute your script:

```
php script.php --file=users.csv
```

You would receive all of the options you already defined.

```
$values = getopt(null, $options);
```

You would have something like this:

```
<?php 

require 'database.php';

$options = ['file:'];

$values = getopt(null, $options);

$lines = file($values['file'], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Rest of the script...
```

I would suggest you read the documentation for the [getopt function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) to help you understand and complete your task.

Comment: I tried this I think there are some error in my code. It keep printing connected to database over and over.